# Jquery, chaining dynamically added selects

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having a problem with [this](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) jQuery plugin that works with `select`s.

[Here](http://www.pastie.org/3056803)'s my HTML and Javascript code. It's a bit large, primarily because of the many `option`s in the `select`.

It works fine at first—it successfully copies the target elements. But after that, it stops working.

I've been trying to fix it for two days and don't know what to do. I was `alert`ing all the variables in the plugin and found out that the backup variable doesn't have the right data and when it creates the element with `#location[2]` it also calls the plugin for `#location[1]`.

**Better description of problem**
I had a three selects with f.e.: brand, model, color

lets say the values could be:

*for brand:* Iphone, Nokia;
*for model:* 4s, 5800;
*for color:* black, white, blue, red

and there' should be only these options:

Iphone -> 4s -> black / white

Nokia -> 5800 -> blue / red

so when I select nokia -> 5800, I didnt want an option "white" or "black" to be shown.

I used jQuery plugin (I linked it above) for this, and it works fine.

The **problem** is:
I have there a button to add another row of this selects and this plugin just stops working after inserting multiple rows. I know the problem is in plugin with variable **backup**

Can anyone tell what is causing the problem?

Comment: Side note: class names should be a minimum 2 characters and start with a letter, rather than a number :)

Comment: its not really class names, its for that "chaining" plugin, based on that class numbers can plugin match OPTIONs from one select with OPTIONs from another :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody that have a trouble with this class, I fixed it this way:

I made a (backup) copy of every select with `$().clone()`. Then after inserting another row of selects, I saved to `$(".select_to_be_chained").data("original_ref", $(".copy") )` reference to that copy of select and than chained it.

To make this work, you have to **edit your jquery.chained.js**:

find this: `$(self).html(backup.html());`

replace it with:

```
// Select data from original_reference (if theres any)
// otherway select data from backup variable
if( ! $(self).data('original_ref') ) $(self).html(backup.html());
else $(self).html( $($(self).data('original_ref')).html() );
```

**USAGE EXAMPLE**

```
// lets assume that we have in html 1st row of selects
// we only need to create a backup elements
var backup_brand = $("select.brand").clone(1);
var backup_model = $("select.model").clone(1);
var backup_color = $("select.color").clone(1);

// now we can chain that 1st row
$("select.color").chained( $("select.model") );
$("select.model").chained( $("select.brand") );

var row = 1;  // how many rows do we have?
function add_row()
{
    row++;
    // lets clone selects
    $("select.brand").clone(1);
    $("select.model").clone(1);
    $("select.color").clone(1);

    $(".all_three_selects").insertBefore("button"); // lets assume that we inserted all three selects in DOM

    // lets chain them
    // 1st we need to set reference to original data (backup)
    $("select.our_cloned_model").data("original_ref", backup_model );
    $("select.our_cloned_color").data("original_ref", backup_color );
    // now we can chain them
    $("select.our_cloned_color").chained( $("select.our_cloned_model") );
    $("select.our_cloned_model").chained( $("select.our_cloned_brand") );
}
```

I haven't tested the example, but it got the idea how I use it and it works, I hope everybody that gonna need it will understand it :)